# Colour of hyperlinks in body of Questions and Answers - not enough contrast

Tags: support, status-completed

Is it possible to change the colour of hyperlinks and visited hyperlinks in the body of questions and answers on the Web Apps Beta?

There is no where near enough contrast, especially for the visited ones. Very difficult to distinguish from main body text.

Example: From an [answer of mine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/web-app-for-prototype-sitemaps-visio-replacement/2162#2162) - there's a link in there somewhere!

[alt text http://i20.photobucket.com/albums/b223/DrShevek/SuperUser/webapps.png](http://i20.photobucket.com/albums/b223/DrShevek/SuperUser/webapps.png)

Comment: I was about to ask the exact same question.  Previously visited links are very hard for me to distinguish from the regular black text on my PC.

Comment: We'll fix this shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has been changed. Compare:

[image]